# Electronic signature

Tags: algorithm, hash, electronic-signature

I was asked to code **electronic signature** for the form. But I can't understand a thing from the description. Is it my qualification or something is missing?

Here is **description**:

```
MAC008(x1, x2, …, xn) := RSA(SHA-1(p(x1)||x1||p(x2)||x2||…||p(xn)||xn),d,n) 

where:

|| - symbol lines connecting
x1, x2, …, xn inquiry parameters;
p function that returns the parameter length. The result is provided as a three-segment number (e.g. 007)
d – RSA secret exponent
n- RSA module
```

Comment: This is a formula for an ecrypted hash, presumably p(x1), x1, etc, are arguments, and functions that return some type of binary data.  I will enumerate in more detail in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that p1 is defined as returning "Hello \x1, how are you" so

```
p1(chris) = "Hello chris, how are you".
```

What this is asking you to do is turn

```
MAC008(chris) = RSA(SHA-1(Hello chris, how are youchris),SOMESECRET,someRSAmodule)
```

Into the modules "signature".  Sha-1 is a hashing algorithm that turns a set of data into a pre determined length string, or hash.  RSA is a signature algorithm that uses a public/private key encryption scheme.  You freely make available the public key, and encrypt the hash with your private key.  This provides no data security, but an individual with your public key can be positive that the data is from you, because this is the only way their public key would work on your data set.